How Do You Reduce a 2-SAT Formula to a Maximum Flow Circuit?
Theoretically, I believe that it is possible to reduce any problem in P to Maximum Flow since it's P-Complete. However, I've been unable to find a natural (many-one) transformation from a 2-SAT formula to a maximum flow circuit such that the maximum flow has a value $k$ iff the formula is satisfiable. Ideally, the process yields a satisfying assignment if one exists. How do you reduce 2-SAT formula to a Maximum Flow Circuit?

If I remember correctly, I think 2-CNF formulas $\varphi$ have a really nice property that, if you consider the graph $G$ of variables and their negations where $x$ has an edge to y if $x\to y$ is a clause (that is, $(\neg x \vee y)$ is a clause), then $\varphi$ is unsatisfiable iff there is an $x$ such that $x$ and $\neg x$ share a cycle in $G$. This gives a pretty natural reduction from 2-UNSAT to s-t reachability, which then has a pretty straightforward reduction to max flow. If this is the kind of thing you're looking for, happy to write a more detailed answer!

@DylanMcKay I am interested in your line of reasoning. I believe you're not mistaken when you say that x
and its negation cannot be reached from one another in the implication graph. I've tried this approach but I was unable to predetermine a value k for the flow while implying an assignment with it because some of the nodes in the same strongly connected component might not be traversed. Therefore, I would be interested in a more detailed answer, that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Before I do write-up something terribly detailed, I want to point out that what I mentioned is technically a reduction from 2-UNSAT to MAXFLOW, rather than 2-SAT to MAXFLOW. The idea would be to make a graph $G$ with nodes $s$ and $t$ so that there is a path from $s$ to $t$ iff there is some literal $x$ which can reach $\neg x$ in the implication graph of $\phi$. And then with a capacity 1 on each edge, the question is just simply whether or not there is a flow $>0$ from $s$ to $t$. I'll write that up if it's helpful! I don't have a many-one reduction in mind from 2-SAT to MAXFLOW.

@DylanMcKay I think that a reduction from 2-UNSAT would be helpful! Upon further inspection, it seems that many NP-Complete are related to the implication graphs of those formulas which makes it difficult to perform the reduction due to their intractability. Therefore, a reduction from 2-UNSAT would be welcome.

Here's an expansion on the my comment.
Let $\textsf{MAXFLOW}=\{\left<G,k\right> \mid \text{ $G$ is a flow network with some flow $f$ where $|f|\ge k$\}}$, and let $\textsf{2-UNSAT}=\{\left<\varphi\right> \mid \text{$\varphi$ is an unsatisfiable 2-CNF Boolean formula}\}.$

Let $\textsf{PATH}=\{\left<G,s,t\right> \mid \text{ There is a path from $s$ to $t$ in $G$}\}$. $\textsf{PATH}$ is a fairly well-known $\mathbf{NL}$-complete problem (you can see Aurora and Barak for more info on that). Any reduction to $\textsf{PATH}$ can be made into a reduction to $\textsf{MAXFLOW}$. Given $G,s,t$, treat $G$ as a flow network with source $s$ and sink $t$ in which each edge has capacity $1$. There is a path from $s$ to $t$ in $G$ iff there is a non-zero flow from $s$ to $t$ in $G$. Given this, we can just describe a reduction from $\textsf{2-UNSAT}$ to $\textsf{PATH}$, and then treat the resulting graph as a flow network as described here.
Given a 2-CNF Boolean formula $\varphi$ with $n$ variables $x_1,...,x_n$, each clause $(x\vee y)$ can be written instead as the logically equivalent clause $(\neg x \to y)$ or equivalently $(\neg y \to x)$. We define the implication graph $G_\varphi$ for $\varphi$ as the graph with nodes $2n$ nodes $\{x_1,...,x_n,\neg x_1,...,\neg x_n\}$. $G_\varphi$ has an edge from literal $x$ to literal $y$ if $(x\to y)$ is equivalent to a clause in $\varphi$. We'll take for granted that $\varphi$ is unsatisfiable iff there is an $i$ such that $x_i$ can reach $\neg x_i$ and $\neg x_i$ and reach $x_i$ in $G_\varphi$. That is, there is a closed walk containing $x_i$ and $\neg x_i$.

With this in mind, given $\varphi$, we want to construct a graph $H_\varphi$ with nodes $s$ and $t$, such that $s$ can reach $t$ iff there is some $i$ such that $G_\varphi$ has a closed walk containing $x_i$ and $\neg x_i$. Let's describe this by building it up from some basic gadgets!
Let $G$ be a graph containing a pair of nodes $x,y$. We can make a corresponding graph $P_{G,x,y}$ with special nodes $s$ and $t$ such that there is a path from $s$ to $t$ in $P_{G,x,y}$ iff $G$ has a path from $x$ to $y$. Let $P_{G,x,y}$ be the graph $G$ but with additional nodes $s$ and $t$, where $s$ has an edge to $x$, and $y$ has an edge to $t$.
We can extend this gadget to to make a graph $C_{G,x,y}$ with dedicated nodes $s$ and $t$ such that $s$ has a path to $t$ iff $G$ has a closed walk containing $x$ and $y$. Simply construct $P_{G,x,y}$ with start node $s$ and end node $v_{middle}$ and $P_{G,y,x}$ with start node $v_{middle}$ and end node $t$.
Now, given $G_\varphi$, we can create $n$ disjoint gadgets $C_{G_\varphi,x_1,\neg x_1},...,C_{G_\varphi,x_n,\neg x_n}$ with their own dedicated source nodes $s_1,...,s_n$ and sink nodes $t_1,...,t_n$. Our goal in determining unsatisfiability is to determine that at least one of these gadgets has a path from its source vertex $s_i$ to its sink vertex $t_i$. What's left to do is create our dedicated source node $s$ with an edge to each gadget's source node $s_i$, and create a dedicated sink node $t$ with an edge from each gadgets dedicated sink node $t_i$. There is a path from $s$ to $t$ iff there is an $i$ such that there is a path from $s_i$ to $t_i$.
And that's the full reduction! I think each detail except for the lemma about closed walks in reachability graphs should be fairly easy to verify, and I think the proof of the closed walk lemma about the implication graph is not too bad!
As far as giving a natural reduction from $\textsf{2-SAT}$ to $\textsf{MAXFLOW}$ goes, I don't have a clear reduction in mind. One could always try analyzing the nondeterministic space $O(\log(n))$ algorithm for $\text{2-SAT}$ to get a similar reduction through $\textsf{PATH}$, or try to look at a circuit computing $\textsf{2-SAT}$ and then go through a reduction from $\textsf{Circuit-Eval}$ to $\textsf{MAXFLOW}$. I'm not sure that either of these would yield anything satisfying, but if you needed an explicit reduction, that's one way to try to find one.

Thank you for your answer! Even though your answer doesn't yield a satisfying assigment, it still answers the question since when $k = 0$ then clearly the maximum flow has a value $k$
iff the formula is satisfiable. I will try to find another reductions that does.
